# Why is my session variable being shared by multiple users in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I have a session variable with a datatable assigned to it. For some reason the results from the datatable (display to user in a GridView) are being shared accross multiple users who are logged in. I thought each session was independent? So when one user makes changes then the other users see those results added to their results. Not sure why. I am not using Application variables.

I initialize the Session variable in Global_asax, then populate it on a button command after the user has filled out the required entries.

```
Imports System.Web.SessionState

Public Class Global_asax
  Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

  Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Session("RDDT") = New DataTable
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Is this tagged PHP for any particular reason?

Comment: I don't see anything on the net about this happening in general.  I know for me when it seems the laws of physics have broken, it always turns out I've overlooked something.  So, in that vain how do you know the RDDT table is changed for other users?  Maybe your test is wrong?

Comment: Each Session is independent. The problem should be somewhere else. When you say "multiple users" do you mean multiple application users logging in the same machine or multiple people in different machines?

Comment: @tucaz Multiple users, meaning we had several users on a phone conference and logged in on their own machines to the application. So as we were comparing we could see the results from one updating on another.

Comment: I agree with @JimW. It's morelikely you overlooked something or is testing in the wrong way

Comment: Fixed: there was a usercontrol that someone else had created that had Public variables. The application was treating them as static. All I did was remove them and changed where in use to Session varibles. I originally overlooked that. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot how hard is to read VB.NET ... long live C# :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, I did overlook something. There was a usercontrol that someone else had created that had Public variables. The application was treating them as static. All I did was remove them and changed where in use to Session varibles. The Application works as intended now.